# Index not used against MySQL SET column

Tags: mysql

I have a large data table containing details by date and across 3 independent criteria with around 12 discreet values for each criteria.  That is, each criteria field in the table is defined as a 12 value ENUM.  Users pull summary data by date and any filtering across the three criteria, including none at all.  To make a single criteria lookup efficient, 3 separate indexes are required (date,CriteriaA), (date,CriteriaB), (date,CriteriaC).  4 indexes if you want to lookup against any of the 3 (date,A,B,C),(date,A,C),(date,B,C),(date,C).

In an attempt to be more efficient in the lookup, I built a SET column containing all 36 values from the 3 criteria.  All values across the criteria are unique and none are a subset of any other.  I added an index to this set (date, set_col).  Queries against this table using a set lookup fails to take advantage of the index, however.  Neither `FIND_IN_SET('Value',set_col)`, `set_col LIKE '%Value%'`, nor `set_col & [pos. in set]` triggers the index (according to explain and overall resultset return speed).

Is there a trick to indexing SET columns?

I tried queries like

```
Select Date, count(*) 
FROM tbl 
where DATE between [Start] and [End] 
and FIND_IN_SET('Value',set_col) 
group by Date
```

I would expect it to run nearly as fast as a lookup against the individual criteria column that has an index against it.  But instead it runs as fast when just an index against DATE exists.  Same number of rows processed according to Explain.

Comment: The history is not interesting. Provide complete sample and desired output for it with detailed explanations according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), and remove unrelated tales. And do not forget to formulate the task.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to index SET columns for arbitrary queries.

A SET type is basically a bitfield, with one bit set for each of the values defined for your set. You could search for a *specific* bit pattern in such a bitfield, or you could search for a range of specific bit patterns, or an inequality, etc. But searching for rows where one specific bit is set in the bitfield is not going to be indexable.

FIND_IN_SET() is really searching for a specific bit set in the bitfield. It will not use an index for this predicate. The best you can hope to do for optimization is to have an index that narrows down the examined rows based on the other search term on `date`. Then among the rows matching the `date` range, the FIND_IN_SET() will be applied row-by-row.

It's the same problem as searching for substrings. The following predicates will not use an index on the column:

```
SELECT ... WHERE SUBSTRING(mytext, 5, 8) = 'word'

SELECT ... WHERE LOCATE(mytext, 'word') > 0

SELECT ... WHERE mytext LIKE '%word%'
```

A conventional index on the data would be alphabetized from the *start* of the string, not from some arbitrary point in the middle of the string. This is why fulltext indexing was created as an alternative to a simple B-tree index on the whole string value. But there's no special index type for bitfields.

I don't think the SET data type is helping in your case.
You should use your multi-column indexes with permutations of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to 3 ENUMs.  Then have

```
INDEX(A, date),
INDEX(B, date),
INDEX(C, date)
```

Those should significantly help with queries like

```
WHERE A = 'foo' AND date BETWEEN...
```

and somewhat help for

```
WHERE A = 'foo' AND date BETWEEN...
  AND B = 'bar'
```

If you will also have queries without A/B/C, then add

```
INDEX(date)
```

Note:  `INDEX(date, A)`  is no better than `INDEX(date)` when using a "range".  That is, I recommend *against* the indexes you mentioned.

`FIND_IN_SET()`, like virtually all other function calls, is not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .  However `enum=const` is sargable since it is implemented as a simple integer.

You did not mention

```
WHERE A IN ('x', 'y') AND ...
```

That is virtually un-indexable.  However, my suggestions are better than nothing.

Comment: Your answer as well as Bill Karwin's convinces me that SET will not achieve what I was hoping for.  However, I disagree with you on the index structure with the ENUMs.  While they are the cheapest indexes for single criteria lookup, it does not allow multi-criteria to pull any faster.  Since each ENUM is only 1 byte, using compound indexes would be minimally more expensive while providing a potential 12x (on average for 2-criteria lookups) to 144x (for 3-criteria) performance gains. In tests, multiple values per criteria (A IN (1,2) AND B IN (3,4) AND C IN (5,6)) used (date,A,B,C) index.

Comment: @ToddfromLA - When `date` is tested as a _range_, `INDEX(date, ...)` will not get past the `date`.   More discussion:  [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)